# Element type is invalid: expected a string [...] Check the render method of 'BurpSimV3'

Tags: reactjs, native

i made a new app with the latest version of react native and it works. Then, i choose to downgrade and create a new app with version 0.44 for compatibility of certain components.. and this:
[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boPjn.jpg)

[Here the code of my index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Dyw.jpg)

And here my ScenaPrincipale.js

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StatusBar,
    ImageBackground,
    StyleSheet    
} from 'react-native';

import Titolo from './titolo';
import Descrizione from './descrizione';
import BottonArea from './bottonarea';
import Banner from './banner';



export default class ScenaPrincipale extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <ImageBackground source={require('../imgs/garfield.jpg')} style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar hidden/>
                <Titolo/>
                <Descrizione/>
                <BottonArea/>
                <Banner/>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

What can i do?

Comment: Check your other components and be sure that you are exporting them properly as told in the error.

Comment: Oh.. Problem solved, that was in <imageBackground>! Thanks :)